# How is this code Thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I was reading a [post on JavaCodeGeeks](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html)

```
public User build() {
    User user = new User(this);
    if (user.getAge() > 120) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(“Age out of range”); // thread-safe
    }
    return user;
}
```

and

```
public User build() {
    if (age > 120) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(“Age out of range”); // bad, not thread-safe
    }
    // This is the window of opportunity for a second thread to modify the value of age
    return new User(this);
}
```

I have a question that, how can one say that the former code is thread safe while the latter is not.

Comment: what does `getAge()` look like ?

Comment: @svasa please refer the post in link

Comment: it could compile, if `age` is a member of the current class. `build` is an instance method.

Comment: local var are always thread safe

Comment: It depends on what the constructor does, and what other functions are available in the class.

Comment: If two threads are working on the same UserBuilder object, then one may change the age of the UserBuilder object after the invariant is checked. If the User object is constructed first, then the invariant is checked against the age value of the User object (which may have been changed before but not after the invariant check). Since this is a newly constructed object, it shouldn't have a reference on any other thread, so the value that is checked in the invariant is the value that the User object will be finalized with. So the invariant will always be met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two threads are using same UserBuilder like this:

```
    User.UserBuilder builder = new User.UserBuilder("Jhon", "Doe");

    // First thread
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        builder.age(30).build();         
    }};

    // Second thread
    Thread t2 = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // Just changing age temporarily in builder.
            builder.age(140);
            builder.age(35).build();         
        }};

   t1.start();
   t2.start();
```

With the threadsafe implementation of  `build()`, you will never have a User with age greater than 120 as Illegal State Exception will be thrown.

In second case it may happen that when t1 checks the condition, `age == 30` but when `new User(this)` is called `age == 140`. In this case you don't get any exception and the invariant about age is broken. This will not happen in first case.

Answer (score 2):

As @AshwineeKJha observes, the post is construing "thread safe" in terms of whether a new `User` object's `age` property is certain to be validated as intended.  Because that property is based on a `final` field, it is certain that a thread that reads the value after the object is fully constructed will see the final value of that property.  Validating the new object after construction instead of validating the builder before construction thus avoids one type of thread-safety problem.

On the other hand, if a builder object is shared between threads, one thread writes its `age` field, and a different thread reads its `age` field, then synchronization between the two threads is required.  A program in which such a combination of events can happen without synchronization is not properly synchronized.  The usual definition of "thread safe" with respect to classes / methods is that the user of a class does not need to perform any external synchronization to ensure proper synchronization when an instance is shared between classes.  Neither code presented is thread safe in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

That comment about thread safety makes the things unclear.

The article seems to hint in the direction of sharing the same instance (`builder`) of `UserBuilder` among multiple threads. That is not such a good idea anyway. The main use of the builder pattern, as described in [Effective Java Item 2](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2), that carefully codes and demonstrates the use of this pattern, is to avoid telescoping constructors while creating consistent instances of immutable classes.

**Note that `User` (if a `final` class) is immutable (and hence thread safe) but `UserBuilder` is not (and hence thread unsafe)**. And that is by design. The idea is to create consistent instances of `User` class via thread-unsafe class that is its builder. So, before you use builders, you must be careful and perhaps be paranoid about sharing them among threads.

If you must share a builder among several threads, then perhaps the suggestion made there is relevant. The suggestion piggybacks on idea of stack confinement of the local variables. The variable `user` is a local variable seen only by the thread that created it. That makes such use thread safe. The second implementation, subtly invokes the thread-unsafe nature of `UserBuilder` itself and causes trouble.

Usually, it is better to just return a new instance of `User` in `build` method and leave the individual checks in the `setters` provided on the builder. And yes, share builder instances among threads judiciously. See Effective Java Item 2.